# How to update ApplicationBadgeIcon in iPhone App?

Tags: ios, nstimer, nstimeinterval, badge, application-icon

I am using applicationiconbadge in my app. I am setting it to 100 and I have to decrement it till 0 and give some alerts in meanwhile. Now when I close my app by pressing homescreen, I can see badge on app icon but its not updating. I have used nstimer to decrement that counter after specific time period and update badgeicon accordingly but it seems not to be working.

Can anyone help me out here ?

Sumit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is sent to the background, the system freezes it and no actual code can be running after that.

What you should do is to schedule [local notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and decrease an application badge from there.

Comment: local notification will help to show alertview. But I want to update app icon badge at the same time.

Comment: Have you read documentation? Local notification can update application badge without showing any alerts.